# How does JAAS load a class implementing LoginModule?

Tags: java, spring, jaas

Is this done via Reflection, or ServiceLoader? I am asking, because I have a custom LoginModule which is supposed to use Spring, but despite having `@Autowired`, the respective bean is not getting populated properly (with the bean defined in the context, which is clearly on the classpath). This leads me to think that the LoginModule implementing class is being loaded using reflection and thus circumventing Spring completely. Is this the case? Can I still somehow use Spring, if so?

Comment: Where is defined your Spring context ? In a webapp or at the server level ? If your beans and your Spring config is in a webapp (so in the webapp classloader), they cannot be seen by your LoginModule which in loaded in the server classloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: yes, this is done using reflection, which effectively goes around Spring and gives you an instantiated object that doesn't have anything `@Autowired`.

However, you could manually initialize your beans in your `LoginModule`'s `initialize()` method. The `LoginModule` class should implement `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware` and you must have a `private static ApplicationContext context`. This way the `context` is injected for you and you can load the beans from there on.

Far from optimal, but it seems to be doing the trick. If anybody has a better solution, please share it, as I would be happy to hear it!